# how to push elements to an array without repeating non of them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I have [this issue here recorded on a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OetU7pqMAkg) for you to understand easier. As you can see, I am selecting some elements from an array and pushing those elements to another array named `$scope.favoriteLeague = [];` in order to do a favorite list of leagues, in that video I am pushing the element as many times as I want and I do not want that, I want to be able to choose only once every element to be on the list, and if the user tries to choose an element that is already on the favorites array, then shows a message.

I am using `lodash` and `angular`, this is the code:

```
$scope.favoriteLeague = []; 

$scope.addToFavorites = function(league) {

   $scope.favoriteLeague.push(league);

};
```

html

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="league in favoriteLeague">

    {{league.name}}

</ion-item>
```

Comment: Maybe look through the array to see if it already contains `league` before calling `.push()`?  Maybe with `.indexOf()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check that it is not in the array. @itcouldevenbeaboat was close but it should have been `=== -1` instead of `!== -1`

```
$scope.addToFavorites = function(league) {

    if ($scope.favoriteLeague.indexOf(league) === -1){
        $scope.favoriteLeague.push(league);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.indexOf()` method is what you ar probably looking for.  Wrap this around the code where `addToFavorites` is called (that way, you don't even call the function, if the value already exists):

```
if ($scope.favoriteLeague.indexOf(league) === -1) {

    . . . your existing call to addToFavorites . . .

}
```

Alternately, if you are using jQuery, you can use the `$.inArray()` method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

actually I got my own solution base on @itcouldevenbeaboat answers

```
$scope.addToFavorites = function(league) {
  if ($scope.favoriteLeague.indexOf(league) === -1) {
    $scope.favoriteLeague.push(league);
  }else {
    console.log('already exists!!!!!');
  }
};
```

Comment: This one is probably wrong, because indexOf returns -1 for not found, which evaluates to true (try `!!-1`). Also if the league is first, indexOf returns 0, which evaluates to false.

Comment: After you've edited your answer, my comment is wrong now. This is a mess anyways.

Comment: I just ask you for sorry me, thanks you all for your help @martinczerwi

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if the array contains the league before pushing it.

```
$scope.addToFavorites = function(league) {

    $scope.favoriteLeague.indexOf(league) === -1 ? $scope.favoriteLeague.push(league) : void 0;

};
```

Comment: Why use a ternary when there is really only one resulting action?  Why not just use an `if`?

Comment: actually I did it this way and now it is not allowing to select anything

Comment: @talemyn can you show me how yo do that ? just a code example, sorry but I did not get you

Comment: The reason is that this code is not working is that it's checking for the wrong condition . . . `!== -1` means that it exists in the array, so the code would only fire if the league was already in the list.  With an empty list, it would never fire.  The check needs to be `=== -1` for this to work, meaning that the league is **not** already in the array.

Comment: @talemyn Because ternary statements let other programmers know you're a BOSS... despite the fact that as your comment pointed out, it is pretty easy to mix up the conditions